# Date is not incrementing in WHILE or FOR loop

Tags: c#, datetime, for-loop, while-loop

What's wrong with the following code? The date is not incrementing in my FOR loop so it goes into an endless loop because the condition is never met. I also tried it with a WHILE loop and got the same result.

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today;
var endDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);
for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date.AddDays(1))
{
   // Some logic here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddDays` doesn't modifies value of `date`, it just returns new instance of `DateTime`, and you're not assigning back incremented value.

It should be

```
for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
```

Comment: To expand on this, it works with an integer because i++ auto-assigns the increment.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the
>   value of this instance.

So, `date.AddDays(1)` doesn't change the value of `date`; it returns a *new* `DateTime` representing the changed value.  If you want to change `date`, do this:

`date = date.AddDays(1);`